# Merge forked git repos and keep both file systems

Tags: git

I'm trying to set up a monorepo from 3 repositories.

I set up a fresh repo and I'm using `git merge remote/branch --allow-unrelated-histories` to merge the projects in.

For the moment I move the file system of each repo into a subfolder, before merging the next one to avoid conflicts on common files.

⬆️ So far that works fine.

2 of the projects I'm trying to merge a have a common root (one is a fork of the other), but today they are considered separate projects and have evolved far apart. But git detects the common ancestry and tries to merge files - which I clearly don't want. Both projects need to be merged in as they are, without git modifying/unifying any files.

I thought about squashing away old commits in the forked project so it forgets the common ancestry. Is there another way?

**Edit:**

I solved it for myself as mentioned above, by getting rid of the common history. But it would still be interesting to know if there is a real solution to this.

```
echo "<FIRST_COMMIT_AFTER_FORK>" > .git/info/grafts
git filter-branch -- --all
```

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you could rewrite a repo (perhaps using `git-filter-repo`) to be in a new subdirectory, and then merge it into the main one.

Comment: Rather than writing directly to `.git/info/grafts`, you should use `git replace`, but if you're going to use filter-branch or filter-repo, the effect in the end is exactly the same: it's just that `git replace` is officially supported while the old grafts mechanism isn't anymore.